# Excel Return Corresponding Row from Non-Blank Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel that calculates the price of software.

```
Product   Qty    Cost
A         1      $100
B
C
D         2      $250
```

I am trying to create a sheet that just returns the Product name from the corresponding non-blank Cost column. So it would look like

```
Product   Cost
A         $100
D         $250
```

I am able to populate the Cost column since that is a basic `INDEX` and `MATCH` but the difficult part is having it populate the Product name only from the non-blank costs. How would I do this?

I was able to find the value of the [*first* non-blank cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967567/2893712) but I could not have it return the subsequent non-blank cells.

Comment: Do you want to include the product if the qty/cost is zero?

Comment: @Jeeped there will never be a 0 value. So I just want to skip blanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the products with non-blank qty/cost,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/SIGN(LEN(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))), ROW(1:1)))
'alternate to discard non-blank, zero value cells
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))<>0), ROW(1:1)))
```

An additional VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formula will return the cost associated with each product.

Comment: This works but there is one small problem specific to my data. The equation for cost is `=SUMIF([@Difference],">0")`. `ISBLANK()` returns FALSE on this. How would I modify your function to ignore any cell that is empty

Comment: *<sigh>* You stated *'there will never be a 0 value'* yet apparently now there is.

Comment: No no, the cell _looks_ blank but your function still sees the blank fields as a valid field.

Comment: If i delete the `SUMIF` from the blank fields, then it returns the correct value using your function

Comment: A zero-length string or a cell that contains zero but is formatted not to show it is not a truly blank cell. If you are using SUMIF then you have cells with zero (e.g. **0**) but are not displaying the value(s).